# use a rest webservice response in another request using jmeter

Tags: json, passwords, jmeter

suppose I have a webservice that generate random password and return json response, this password is used in the following request. is there anyway to do this in jmeter, i.e to extract the password from the first response and use it in the next request

Answer (score 1):

We have  [Regualr Expression Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html)  Or [JSON Path Extractor](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JSONPathExtractor/) in JMeter to extract the values from 1 response & use it in subsequent requests.

Answer (score 1):

As [Vinoth S](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2897008/vinoth-s) said, JSON extractor is the way to go. You can download it from [here](http://jmeter-plugins.org). Document how to use it is [here](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JSONPathExtractor/). Just put it in request from which you want to extract, type vairable_name that you will use in the next request as ${variable_name}, JSON Path is quite easy to set, probably, if the response is not to complicateg just the property name from JSON will be enough, or something like $.varName and you're ready to go.